# Trouble with adding Scrollbar to Canvas in Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I'm attempting to add a scrollbar widget to the Canvas in my program. The program is a basically a table made by adding a Canvas to the master and then adding Frames to the Canvas using .grid(). I've included the relevant portions of code. I'm not sure what it is that I'm doing incorrectly.

```
from Tkinter import *    
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master)
title_frame = Frame(canvas, bd=2, relief=RIDGE)
...
canvas.pack()
vbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
master.mainloop()
```

[This is what my program is producing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHsQv.png)

Comment: I think you wanted to include the line `canvas.config(yscrollcommand=ybar.set)` instead of `canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set)` since the previous lines are about `vbar` and not `hbar`.

Comment: @j_4321 I accidentally typed that in when I was posting my question.

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the output you say it does. Also, the canvas can't scroll widgets added using `.grid()`. It can only scroll objectr create on the canvas itself (eg: with `create_window`). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3092341/7432

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate.  Look at some of the 'Related' questions on the right sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `side=LEFT` when I packed the canvas and the scrollbar is now on the right of the canvas instead of below. It is because the default side for pack is `TOP`.

```
from Tkinter import *    
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT)
vbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
master.mainloop()
```

[image: scrollbar]

Edit: I think I understand your problem now: I tried to display both horizontal and vertical scrollbars but I didn't manage to do it with the pack layout. I suggest you to use grid instead:

```
from Tkinter import *    
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
hbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)
hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
vbar = Scrollbar(master, orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
vbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)

canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I made the change you suggested and the program still does not display a Scrollbar. Any other suggestions or things I should try?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you a solution using grid instead of pack.

Comment: Thanks, I'm away from my computer now, but when I get back to it I'll try it out. I really appreciate the help you've given me.